# Krajee File Input ajax upload multiple fields same form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Krajee the Bootstrap File Input plugin to perform an upload via AJAX call.

I've a form where I can dinamically add fieldset to cointain multiple files (and each file can have description and other fields):

```
<a id="add">Add files</a>

$("#id").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"text",
    url: "get_fieldset.php",
    data: {  },
    success: function(data, status) {
      $("#container").append(data);  
      $("#container").find(":file").fileinput();          
    }
});
```

get_fieldset.php:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>File</label>
      <input type="file" name="f[]" class="f">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <input type="text" name="descr[]" class="form-control descr" value="">
    </div>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

My goal is to click SUBMIT button and upload all files with `$('.f').fileinput('upload');` but showing progress bar related to all files. And i've to associate each `.descr` to correspondenting file.

```
$("#container").find(":file").fileinput();
```

has to be edited to do it. I know there's a `uploadExtraData` option, but how to associate the correct descr input? cause i don't have unique name but i can retrieve it by class only.

I hope you understand me.